# Avoid before trigger to fire on case assignment rules

Tags: trigger, case

I have a before trigger on case object which doesn't allow users to edit the record if it is in queue.
I have an assignment rule which assign the owner to queue  and the before trigger is firing which should happen.
I want to stop my before triggers to fire if the update is on case assignment rule

I can achieve this without using case assignment rule but since i am using case object wanted to use standard functionality of case assignment rule

Comment: Its unclear to me what your real question is. Are you having problems rewriting your trigger? If so, I recommend you post post your code, tell us where you're stuck and I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: 1) Be sure you have read: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm ; 2) Are we talking about new Cases here or some update operation on Cases where explicit request for Case reassignment execution was requested?